# Data provided to import into Oracle only has day and month. Year is missing. What DATE type to use?

Tags: oracle

Data provided to import into Oracle only has day and month. Year is missing. I need to run some queries to calculate number of days between dates. Eg. Checkin date: 03-April and Check out: 07-May.
What DATE type to use?

Comment: So is there a default year?

Comment: No year mentioned in task. We need a solution without year.

Comment: If you haven't been given a year then you'll need to apply one - either the current year, or an arbitrary fixed one. But bear in mind you'll need to handle the in/out spanning year-end - if you're passed 31-Dec and 01-Jan for example. And you won't be able to deal with leap years properly with an arbitrary fixed year..

Comment: Not all yearly **calendars** are equally formed. Calendars have 365 or 366 days. For example, how many days are between Feb 28 and March 1st? One day or two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to run some queries to calculate number of days between dates. Eg. Check in date: 03-April and Check out: 07-May.

In general, you need a year to unambiguously calculate the number of days between two dates as you need to account for leap years (and, if you are being particularly precise, leap seconds).

You can use several methods:

1. Assume that your dates are always going to be in a non-leap year. Then you can pick any non-leap year and use it in your query as a default year.
2. Assume that your dates are always going to be in a leap year. Then you can pick any leap year and use it in your query as a default year.
3. Assume that your dates are always going to be of the current year.

They all have flaws:

- If the assumption is wrong then you will get the wrong value if the dates are either side of `Feb-29`.
- If you get the value `Feb-29` then 1 & 3 can raise exceptions.

> What DATE type to use?

If you are talking about how to store the value in a table then either store the value in a `VARCHAR2` if you want to store the raw values or chose one of the three assumptions above and use a `DATE` data type and apply the default year.

For example, you could store the raw data and calculate the `DATE` values for the default year:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  check_in            VARCHAR2(20),
  check_out           VARCHAR2(20),
  check_in_1970       DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_DATE(check_in || 1970 DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'DD-MonthYYYY')),
  check_out_1970      DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_DATE(check_in || 1970 DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'DD-MonthYYYY')),
  check_in_2020       DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_DATE(check_in || 2020 DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'DD-MonthYYYY')),
  check_out_2020      DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_DATE(check_in || 2020 DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'DD-MonthYYYY')),
);

INSERT INTO table_name (check_in, check_out) VALUES ('03-April', '07-May');
INSERT INTO table_name (check_in, check_out) VALUES ('01-January', '31-December');
INSERT INTO table_name (check_in, check_out) VALUES ('29-February', '29-February');
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT check_in,
       check_out,
       check_out_1970 - check_in_1970 AS diff_1970,
       check_out_2020 - check_in_2020 AS diff_2020
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | CHECK_IN | CHECK_OUT | DIFF_1970 | DIFF_2020 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 03-April | 07-May | 34 | 34 |
> | 01-January | 31-December | 364 | 365 |
> | 29-February | 29-February | *null* | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9da5978799951d9aa616554f77f0322e)*

Comment: Plus one for the leap seconds alone.